# Is there a sequence such that $\sum{a_n}$ diverges but $\sum{na_n}$converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a (real) sequence such that $\sum{a_n}$ diverges but $\sum{na_n}$converges?

Comment: Not if $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no such sequence.  Suppose that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ converges.  Then, since $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is monotone and bounded (it goes to zero), we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}na_n$ converging by Abel's test (or by Dirichlet's test); see [Abel's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test)  and [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)  .

Answer (score 7):

The idea is (see applications of Abel transformation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Applications)):

If $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent and $v_n \to 0$ monotonically, then $\sum_n u_n v_n$ is convergent.

Here, take $u_n=na_n$ and $v_n=\frac 1 n$.

So the answer is no.